# How to create android onitemclick for layout change process?

Tags: java, android

i've created list in first layout from server, and now i want to go to next layout when i choose the content in current layout it'll go through with that content using onlistitemclick? how can i use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have data assigned to your list by some adapter, now you can set onItemClick listener for your List. The method you should use, is

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list_view, View row_view, int position, long id)
```

where you can obtain the **position** of selected item. The data stored in your list should be stored in some array and accessible using method .get(position). Then you can work with it.

Comment: Give me some example for this method. And, also i've one java file (and 3 xml layout file) that include all the contents, so i need a layout change method in same java file, i can't understand this method which was given by you.